# Download Android Studio on Linux Debian - download does not start

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, debian

I'm attempting to download Android Studio on Debian (version 8.4 "jessie") but the download does not even start.  I'm using this page:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

All that happens is that I get a popup that appears for about 1-2 seconds that states:
"Now downloading the Android SDK Tools!
Because you've chosen to download only the Android SDK tools (and not Android Studio), there are no setup procedures to follow. For information about how to keep your SDK tools up to date, refer to the SDK Manager guide."

That's all I get... nothing gets downloaded.

Comment: Same here. Disabling any adblocker didn't work either.

Comment: Use Chromium, not Firefox!!

Comment: That is not a very well-made site with regards to navigation/routing. There are no direct links to the Linux/Mac installation instructions, for example.